# I'm stuck with my React app in production with webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, web-hosting, production-environment, polyfills

For my React application, I am using a Google Maps API key for a component, as well as a mail sending library.
The API key and password required for mail sending are **sensitive data that cannot be stored in simple variables**.

In **production mode**, to secure these sensitive variables, I created a folder called "other" **outside of the "public_html" folder**. 
In this "other" folder, I created a file called ".env" with my various variables inside, all starting with **"REACT_APP_" as advised**. 
To access these variables in my code, I navigated to the "other" folder and accessed the .env file with the command:
`require('dotenv').config({ path: '../other/.env' });`
I should then be able to get my variable:
`const ww = process.env.REACT_APP_COCO`

However, when I run the ***npm run build*** command to deploy the application in production, I get the following error:

> "BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js
> core modules by default. This is no longer the case. Verify if you
> need this module and configure a polyfill for it. If you want to
> include a polyfill, you need to: - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: {
> "os": require.resolve("os-browserify/browser") }' - install
> 'os-browserify' If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use
> an empty module like this: resolve.fallback: { "os": false }"

**I have modified the "webpack.config.js" file, specifically the "resolve.fallback" by setting the value to false for "path", etc., but nothing works.**

So, **I decided to simplify by creating a new application**

- with "npx create-react-app nameofmyapp",
- installing "dotenv" with "npm install dotenv",
- and creating the .env file with my variable "REACT_APP_COCO=8" at the root of my
  application (i.e., at the same level as the "public" folder).
- Then,
  in my Home component, I accessed my variable with "REACT_APP_COCO":

```
import React from 'react'

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      {process.env.REACT_APP_COCO}
    </div>
          )
     }
export default Home
```

**At this point, I had no webpack problems or errors, and the value 8 was displayed**.

**The problem arises when I want to host this application on my host's server**. 
So, I added **a condition to distinguish between the development and production environments**

```
import React from 'react'

if(process.env.NODE_ENV==='production'){
  require('dotenv').config({ path: '../other/.env' });
}
const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
       {process.env.REACT_APP_COCO}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

And I ran the "npm run build" command, and got the error:

> "Failed to compile. Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in
> ……./node_modules/dotenv/lib".

I ran npm install dotenv@latest but I still got the message about including a polyfill for the "os" module.

I then tried **modifying the "webpack.config.js"** file with the following code:

```
module.exports = {
// ...
resolve: {
fallback: {
"fs": false,
"os": false,
"path":false
},
},
plugins: [
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
process: 'process/browser',
}),
],
};
```

But I still got the same error. I have been searching for a solution for over three hours, but I cannot find one. This is a blocking issue because I need to access the "other" folder containing my .env file, which contains the API key that I need to use Google Maps. **I have simplified the problem as much as possible so that you can help me effectively**. I eagerly await your suggestions, as I am stuck and cannot find a solution.

Drarig29 solution => 
What I done:

```
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');
module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        fallback: {
        "fs": false,
        "os": false,
        "path":false
        },
        },
  // ...

  plugins: [
    new Dotenv({
        path: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '../other/.env' : '.env',
    })
  ],
};
```

The problem now is that **in production it reads the .env file which is at the root of my app, and not the .env file in the "other" folder of the server.**

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `dotenv` alone in Webpack because it uses the filesystem to read a file at runtime. This is not possible in a browser.

You should use [dotenv-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack) instead (you can uninstall `dotenv` as `dotenv` is included in `dotenv-webpack`).

You'll need to add this plugin to your `webpack.config.js` ([docs](https://github.com/mrsteele/dotenv-webpack#add-it-to-your-webpack-config-file)).

With this plugin, you won't do any `require('dotenv').config()` in your code anymore, but do it in `webpack.config.js` instead.

To load a different file in production, you can do something like:

```js
plugins: [
  new Dotenv({
    path: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '../../path/to/other.env' : '.env',
  })
]
```

Here is a tutorial which looks nice: https://prateeksurana.me/blog/using-environment-variables-with-webpack/

Once configured properly, all uses of `process.env.{variable_name}` will be replaced with the actual value of `{variable_name}` in the generated bundle.

Comment: The problem now is that in production it reads the .env file which is at the root of my app, and not the .env file in the "other" folder of the server.

Comment: You need to build two different bundles. One for production, one for development. Choosing between the two env files is done **at build time**, not at runtime. You can't magically read from different files when deploying the same bundle in different environments.